# Node/express - cancel multer photo upload if other fields validation fails

Tags: node.js, express, multer, node.js-fs

I have multer as middleware before editing user function. The thing is that multer uploads photo no matter what, so I am wondering if there is a way to somehow cancel upload if e.g. email is invalid. I tried to delete uploaded image through function via fs.unlink if there is validation error within edit function, but I get "EBUSY: resource busy or locked, unlink" error. I guess that multer uploads at the same time while I try to delete image.
Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

on your function make a try/catch block and handle on error throw

```
import { unlink } from 'node:fs/promises';
import path from 'path'

// code ...

// inside your function

const img  = req.file // this needs to be outside the try block

try {

     // your code, throw on failed validation

} catch (e) {
   if (img) {
        // depends on where you store in multer middleware
        const img_path = path.resolve(YOUR_PATH, img.filename) 
        await unlink(img_path);

        console.log(`deleted uploaded ${ img_path }`);
    }

    // revert transaction or anything else
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays, applications usually separates uploading file API from data manipulating API for some features like previewing/editing image. Later, they can run a background job to clean unused data.

But if it's necessary in your case, we can use multer's builtin `MemoryStorage` to keep file data in memory first, then save it to disk after validation completes.

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const multer = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });
const fs = require('fs');

app.post("/create_user_with_image", upload.single('img'), (req, res) => {
  // Validation here

  fs.writeFile(`uploads/${req.file.originalname}`, req.file.buffer, () => {
    res.send('ok');
  });
});
```

**Note:** as multer documentation said, this solution can cause your application to run out of memory when uploading very large files, or relatively small files in large numbers very quickly.